# Unwanted array indexes when using JSON.stringify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I use `JSON.stringify` method to pass an array to server.

I have an array that has 4 elements:

```
arr[10] = 1;
arr[20] = 1;
arr[30] = 1;
arr[40] = 1;
```

Then i do this:

```
arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Then send it to the server:

```
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: baseurl+"profile/mprofile/action/ratings/add_ratings",
                    data:{"checkbox":checkbox,"review":review,"speciality":speciality,"arr":arr},
                    success: function(data, status) {  

                        jQuery('#header-error').html(data);
                    } 
                });
```

I am getting the array in PHP with:

```
    $arr = $this->ci->input->post('arr');
    $arr = json_decode($arr);
    print_r($arr) ; die ;
```

the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
    [19] => 
    [20] => 1
    [21] => 
    [22] => 
    [23] => 
    [24] => 
    [25] => 
    [26] => 
    [27] => 
    [28] => 
    [29] => 
    [30] => 1
    [31] => 
    [32] => 
    [33] => 
    [34] => 
    [35] => 
    [36] => 
    [37] => 
    [38] => 
    [39] => 
    [40] => 1
)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how javascript arrays work. When you set value to an index that is out of range, array is expanded, value is successfully set and all 'missing' values are set to `undefined`.

You are spoiled by PHP behaviour that blends the difference between arrays and dictionaries (or "associative arrays", in PHP talk).

To avoid this behaviour, just create a dictionary in javascript instead of array.

```
var arr = {};
arr[10] = 1;
arr[20] = 2;
```

Also, on PHP side you should pass `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode`.

```
json_decode($arr, true)
```

This will make it return array instead of stdclass.

Comment: +1, though you might want to add that on the php side the second parameter for json_decode is needed to be set to true, or you'll end up with stdclass objects instead of arrays.

Comment: That's true. Object and array are 2 different things. Don't forget the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

How do you initialize arr? You probably want to use an object instead of an Array. For example:

```
var arr = {};
arr[10] = 1;
arr[20] = 1;
arr[30] = 1;
arr[30] = 1;
var jsonified = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(jsonified);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript work a bit differently than in PHP. You don't actually have an array with 4 elements, you have one with 41 elements *right from the start*. For example, when you say `arr[ 10 ] = 1`, every array element between 0 and 9 are automatically assigned `undefined`.

I suggest you switch the logic around: instead of using array keys to track values, use array values instead:

```
arr = [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ];
```

Or, if you need other than binary values, use objects:

```
arr = [
    { score: 10, value: 1 },
    { score: 20, value: 5 }
];
```